# regex to extract value from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex to extract a value from a string but can´t make it work :( regex is hard!

```
const myString = "the user id is: [user]10[/user]"
```

this is my regex

```
(?:[user])([\s\S]*)(?:[\/user])
```

but I´m not getting a match

Comment: You need to escape the brackets around 'user'.  Right now it's a character class of u,s,e, OR r

Comment: Do you just need to get `10` from this example? Also, is this format constant, except for that number between `[user]`?

Comment: yes exactly. just want to extact whatever is between [user] and [/user]

Comment: You can simply do: `myString.match(/\d+/)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Adding matching square brackets literally by adding `\` before them will allow obtaining the match `id` value, like following

```
(?:\[user\])([\s\S]*)(?:\[\/user\])
```

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I just want to extract the actual value in this case 10.

Comment: sure, it is possible to do like following "the user id is: [user]10[/user]".match(/(?:\[user\])([\s\S]*)(?:\[\/user\])/)[1]

Comment: that returns: " user id is: [user]10[/use"

Comment: correct usage 
`"the user id is: [user]10[/user]".match(/(?:\[user\])([\s\S]*)(?:\[\/user\])/)[1]`